# jquery drag and drop function

Tags: jquery-ui

This function takes an li element and adds it to another ul element.  After this code is fired the jquery events attached to the children spans of the li element do not fire the first time they are clicked.

```
function AddToDropBox(obj) {
    $(obj).children(".handle").animate({ width: "20px" }).children("strong").fadeOut();
    $(obj).children("span:not(.track,.play,.handle,:has(.btn-edit))").fadeOut('fast');
    $(obj).children(".play").css("margin-right", "8px");
    $(obj).css({ "opacity": "0.0", "width": "284px" }).animate({ opacity: "1.0" });
    if ($(".sidebar-drop-box ul").children(".admin-song").length > 0) {
        $(".dropTitle").fadeOut("fast");
        $(".sidebar-drop-box ul.admin-song-list").css("min-height", "0");
    }
    if (typeof SetLinks == 'function') {
        SetLinks();
    }
    if(document.getElementById("ctl00_cphBody_hfRemoveMedia").value===""||document.getElementById("ctl00_cphBody_hfRemoveMedia").value===null)
    {
        document.getElementById("ctl00_cphBody_hfRemoveMedia").value=(obj).attr("mediaid");
    }
    else
    {
        var localMediaIDs=document.getElementById("ctl00_cphBody_hfRemoveMedia").value;
        localMediaIDs=    localMediaIDs.replace((obj).attr("mediaid"),"");
        document.getElementById("ctl00_cphBody_hfRemoveMedia").value=localMediaIDs+", "+(obj).attr("mediaid");
    }
}
```

Is there something missing in this code that would cause that?

**UPDATE**

thats exactly what I am using for the jquery sortable feature that actually calls the addtoDropbox Method().

```
// Make our dropbox a selectable & sortable.  
    $(".sidebar-drop-box ul").sortable({  
        connectWith: '.admin-left',  
        tolerance: "intersect",  
        handle: ".handle",  
        opacity: "0.5",  
        receive: function(event, ui) {  
            **AddToDropBox(ui.item)**;  
        },  
        start: function(event, ui) {  
            $(".sidebar-drop-box ul.admin-song-list").css("min-height", "70px");  
            isDraggingSong = true;  
            //soundManager.stopAll();  
            //$(".btn-stop").removeClass("btn-stop");  
        },  
        stop: function(event, ui) {  
            if ($(".sidebar-drop-box ul").children("li").length == 0) {  
                $(".dropTitle").fadeIn();  
            }  
        }  
    }); //.selectable({ filter: 'li', cancel: '.btn-stop,.btn-play,.notes,.btn-del,span.remove' });  

    // Do the same for our playlist.  
    $(".admin-left").sortable({  
        opacity: '0.5',  
        tolerance: "intersect",  
        handle: ".handle",  
        appendTo: 'appentToHolder',  
        items: "li.admin-song",  
        update: function(event, ui) {  
            $(ui.item).css("opacity", "0.0").animate({ opacity: "1.0" }, "medium");  
            if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == "7.0") {  
                $(ui.item).css("margin-bottom", "-6px");  
            }  
        },  
        receive: function(event, ui) {  
            AddToLeftList(ui.item);  
        },  
        start: function(event, ui) {  
            $(".admin-left li.ui-selected").removeClass("ui-selected");  
            isDraggingSong = true;  
            //soundManager.stopAll();  
            //$(".btn-stop").removeClass("btn-stop");  
        },  
        stop: function(event, ui) {  
            CheckLeftList();  

        },  
        connectWith: '.sidebar-drop-box ul'  
    }).selectable({ filter: 'li.admin-song', cancel: '.head *,.btn-stop,.btn-play,.notes,.btn-del,span.remove' }); // added .head * to fix bug# 1013
```

the bold line calls the function I added previously, which places the li element.

I am not sure exactly where the disconnect happens, but i know between these 2 code segments that it breaks something and the next click doesn't not work on the source ul.  i ahve been struggling with this for days.  I cant turn this back to my boss this shape...lol

thanx

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like this function is adding something to a list.

- This function first does a couple of
  CSS changes to obj and it's
  descendants.
- Then it goes and calls    the global 
  function SetLinks (if    it is
  defined).
- And thirdly it    sets the value of
  the element
  "ctl00_cphBody_hfRemoveMedia", which 
  is probably some kind of input.

Looks like this was pasted together from at least two other functions and would need refactoring.

I'm guessing that the cause for your lost events might be somewhere near a call to AddToDropBox.

Comment: Updated post everything after UPDATE